# JS complex operation of the selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, syntax-highlighting, highlight

**Great minds JavaScript, please help.
I need to deal with the complex operation of the selected text.**

*I have some text with a lot of html tags, and I need to get a function that returns the following result:*

The user selects text in a particular tag with the class, for example `<div class="text">`,

and the function is activated in the event that:

```
$('.text').mouseup(function (e){...});
```

- returns the beginning of the selection
- returns the end of the
- selection identifies a particular tag, with his class

Moreover:

- the number of characters to be given html tags,
- but you can exclude
  some tags example ,

Ok, some code, what I have:

```
$(function () {
    $('.text').mouseup(function (e){
        $(this).highlight(getSelectionText());
   })
})
```

[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LgCjT/1/)

> Here we highlight the desired part of the text, but did not return the
> correct position
>
> In addition, the text is released coincidentally
> characters, and I need it for the position

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#detailBoxParagraph').mouseup(function (e){
        var selectedText = getSelectionText();
        $(this).removeHighlight();
        $(this).highlight(selectedText);

        var txt = $(this).text();
        var pos = [];
        var i = txt.indexOf(selectedText);
        if(i > -1) {
            pos.push({"start": i+1, "end": i + selectedText.length});
        }
        while (i != -1) {
            i = txt.indexOf(selectedText, i + 1);
            if(i > -1) {
               pos.push({"start": i+1, "end": i + selectedText.length});
            }
        }
        console.log(pos);
   })
   //alertSelection();
})
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is not appropriate because: - does not result in the number of characters, and in rastolyanii (left, top) - not taken into account if the allocated tag, and I on the contrary they are needed

Comment: I updated my code above. You can also check the code here(http://jsfiddle.net/LgCjT/152/).

Comment: Again, there is no accounting html tags, as well as my browser (Chrome) somehow collapsing when I try to highlight a few times

Comment: yes it doesn't account the html tags. What I did is that I locate all the location of the text that was highlighted base in character. For example: var str = "Sample text Sample"; if I highlight "text", The positions of the "text" text will be 8-11 wherein 8 is the start and 11 is the end of selection.

Comment: Is that what you mean @serge?